# Wrap html content inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem which seems to be simple but some how I cannot figure the best way to do it.

Below is my html Structure:

```
  <div id="PasswordStrengthBorder" style="position: absolute; display: inline;
  height:3px; top: 379px; left: 556px; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; 
  padding: 2px; width: 200px;"> </div>

  <div class="BarIndicator" id="PasswordStrengthBar" style="position: absolute;
  display: inline; height: 5px; top: 381px; left: 559px; width: 100px; 
  background-color: blue;">
  </div>

  <span style="position: absolute; top: 389px; left: 556px; font-size: 75%; 
  display: inline-block; width: 200px;">3 more characters, At least 1 more symbol,
  1 Upper case characters, 1 lower case character</span>
```

All this is dynamic html and is added to the html page by a plugin. I need to wrap all these three elements in a single div. What is the correct way of doing it?

Comment: Could you also post the parent/child/sibling elements of these, so we can see find the best selector to use for them.

Comment: How does your plugin add them to the page. Could you specify a containing div to the plugin, or edit the plugin to add a containing div?

Comment: There is no immediate parent of these controls. The parent has a number of other controls as well but I need to wrap only these three.

Comment: Html structure varies? or only the content of the 3 divs?

Comment: I can add a class to all the three elements to improve the selection process....

Comment: Select the three, cut them out of the page and add them back into the "container" div?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
$('.yourClass').wrapAll('<div id="wrapper">');
```

http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/

Comment: I can add a class to each of these to improve the selection process if required.

Comment: Well that's something. I see the problem with my code now: every selected element gets wrapped instead of all in one div... looking for another solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div id="parent">

</div>
```

Then when you dynamically create the new simply call

```
$('#parent').html().append(dynamicallyGeneratedHtml);
```

Comment: If this is occurring through an Ajax call, he probably has to empty it first, or this same **dynamicallyGeneratedHtml** will be added again and again, mixing old data with new data. `$("#parent").html("");`

Comment: or simply `$('#parent').html(dynamicallyGeneratedHtml);`

Comment: i presumed that the call occurred 3 times.

Comment: .html() with no string passed tries to return #parent's content, `$('#parent').html().append(dynamicallyGeneratedHtml);` would not work @JustinSchuhmann

Answer (score 0):

If the content of the 3 divs is dynamic (but not structure), you can set a template and concatenate the data with json

```
$.post('web/serverside', function(data){

            $.each(data, function(i,obj)
            {                           

                $(#mydiv).html('<div id="PasswordStrengthBorder" style="position: absolute; display: inline;'+
                'height:3px; top: 379px; left: 556px; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px;'+
                'padding: 2px; width: 200px;">'+obj['value1'])+'</div>'+
                '<div class="BarIndicator" id="PasswordStrengthBar" style="position: absolute;'+
                'display: inline; height: 5px; top: 381px; left: 559px; width: 100px;'+ 
                'background-color: blue;">'+obj['value2'])+'</div>'+
                '<span style="position: absolute; top: 389px; left: 556px; font-size: 75%;'+ 
                'display: inline-block; width: 200px;">'+obj['value3'])+'</span>');                                 
            }); 

}, 'json');
```